# Algorithm for finding the closest set of measurment to certain measurment

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a collection of measurments, example:
measurment #1: { 200, 350, 712, 1023, 1430, 1555, 1800, 2036, 2569 }
measurment #2: { 165, 400, 974, 1124, 1600, 1893, 1919, 2032, 2654, 2932 }
...
measurment #N: { 234, 454, 879, 1432, 1877, 2000, 2543, 2876 }

The order of the elements in each measurment is important.
Each element will have higher value than the previous.
The number of elements in each measurment may vary,
but they should not vary to much.

Now i am getting as an input a new measurment 
(lets say: { 212, 354, 978, 1222, 1454, 1922, 2013, 2432, 2987})
and should find the closest measurment from the collection of measurment i already possess.

My question is what algorithm should i use for this task ?

More:
1. It is also possible to extend the task in such meatter that instead input of one measurment i will be given a small collection of measurments.
2. Each element in a measurment represent time passed in second from the begining.
The measuring is stoped when reached 3600 seconds (1 hour), therfore the minimal posible value will be 0 and the maximal will be 3599.
The events creating each element in the measurment to be created is affected by a human behaviour.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: well, this question has one minor problem: no definition of "equal measurements". equal distribution of density, same number of values, equal values / do all values have the same priority, etc.?

Comment: What is the distance metric? Your question makes little sense without context. You need to define the distance between two set of measurements before working out the best algorithm.

Comment: Please explain the full experiment. You mentioned human behaviour, are you trying to identify people using their behaviour? Then what is that behaviour? please give all the information related to the experiment.

Comment: I belive that the parameters that maters regarding the "equal measurements" will be that the pattern is as closet betwean the two measurments, that the time passed betwean the events resembles, that the total or local standart deviation resembles.
All values have the same weigth, none is more important than another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your data is "fuzzy", one class of algorithms you may want to look into is [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). By fuzzy I mean that two sets are almost align, but one set may have extra elements inserted, removed compared to the other and the matching elements "almost" matches.

In these types of algorithms you typically define a distance score by defining a penalty for inserting/removing an element in the alignment and a penalty score for two elements not quite matching.
In your case you may define an insert / delete penalty of "100" seconds for inserting an extra timing event, and a two-element distance score as the absolute distance in seconds.
Given that definition you can easily find and modify a needleman-wunsch algorithm implementation or something similar. This will give you the distance between two small sets of measurements in an acceptable amount of time.
However, if your number of elements in your measurements is huge or your number of sets is huge, and you need the answer in say milliseconds, then it is a rather difficult problem unless you can find a lot of good constraints for your problem.

The above is just an example, it all boils down to the context. Is your data noisy? How "noisy", with extra elements in the middle, start or end or just slightly off in position? plus a ton of other questions.

Choosing and implementing fuzzy algorithms can range between pretty easy to near impossible all depending on the context and what you are going to use the result for. Does it need to be exact or "just good enough". Does it need to be fast, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I've decided to try to use the needleman-wunsch algorithm you have mentioned with some adaptations and to consider to prior to the use of it remove measurements which with high probability does not resemble to the one compared.
I do not need an exact results only approximation and it may have some noise of all types meantioned by you, but the noise is not expacted to be significant.

Comment: @LEyahoo you may also want to have a look at the "Levenshtein distance". This is closely related to needleman-wunsch, but the Levenshtein result is a distance measurement where needleman-wunsch gives you the best alignment. In short, the Levenshtein distance tells you the number of changes you have to make A look like B, but you can easily use your own weights, such that inserting an item cost the same as say a time distance of 100. It is very easy to find implementations online of both algorithm. You will only need to tweak the "equals" measurement to some simple time distance score.

Answer (score 0):

Find the squared sum of errors of your new measure with each measurement in your collection. Then return the one from your collection with the smallest error.

```
var measures = [
 [1, 2, 3, 4],
 [10, 20, 30, 40],
 [66, 77, 88, 99],
 [101, 202, 303, 404]
];

// ignores measurements that aren't the same length as the data
// uses the squared sum of differences (errors)
function findClosest(data) {
  var minError = 0x7FFFFFFF; // max 32bit signed int
  var result = null;
  for(var i=0; i < measures.length; i++) {
    if(data.length !== measures[i].length) { continue; }
    var error = 0;
    for(var j=0; j < data.length; j++) {
      error += Math.pow(measures[i][j] - data[j], 2);
    }
    if(error < minError) {
      minError = error;
      result = measures[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// allows data that is different length than measurements by trying to best fit each element of data to an element of the tested measurement
// uses the squared sum of differences (error)
function findClosestV2(data) {
  var minError = 0x7FFFFFFF; // max 32bit signed int
  var result = null;
  for(var i=0; i < measures.length; i++) {
    var measure = measures[i];
    var error = 0;
    var minLocalError = 0x7FFFFFFF;
    for(var j=0; j < data.length; j++) {
      for(var k=0; k < measure.length; k++) {
        var localError = Math.pow(measure[k] - data[j], 2);
        if(localError < minLocalError) {
          minLocalError = localError;
        }
      }
      error += minLocalError;
    }
    if(error < minError) {
      minError = error;
      result = measures[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// allows data that is different length than measurements by trying to best fit each element of data to an element of the tested measurement
// uses the average of the absolute error % using the previous measurement as the ideal value
function findClosestV3(data) {
  var minError = 0x7FFFFFFF; // max 32bit signed int
  var result = null;
  for(var i=0; i < measures.length; i++) {
    var measure = measures[i];
    var error = 0;
    var minLocalError = 0x7FFFFFFF;
    for(var j=0; j < data.length; j++) {
      for(var k=0; k < measure.length; k++) {
        var localError = Math.abs( (measure[k] - data[j]) / measure[k] );
        if(localError < minLocalError) {
          minLocalError = localError;
        }
      }
      error += minLocalError;
    }
    // average of sum of error percentages
    error /= data.length;
    if(error < minError) {
      minError = error;
      result = measures[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(findClosest([2,3,4,5])); // [1,2,3,4]
console.log(findClosest([70,80,90,100])); // [66,77,88,99]
console.log(findClosest([9,19,304,405])); // [101,202,303,404]

console.log(findClosestV2([404])); // [101,202,303,404]
console.log(findClosestV2([66,67,68,69])); // [66,77,88,99]
console.log(findClosestV2([9,19,304,405])); // [10,20,30,40]

console.log(findClosestV3([404])); // [101,202,303,404]
console.log(findClosestV3([66,67,68,69])); // [66,77,88,99]
console.log(findClosestV3([9,19,304,405])); // [10,20,30,40]
```

Comment: This answer does a lot of assumptions about the data and the question asked. For example, all comparisons of uneven length score best score: findClosest([404]) finds [1,2,3,4] for no good reason. Without understanding the problem you have to make a lot of random assumptions.

Comment: @Holstebroe - Yes, the question is pretty vague. For the initial version of the answer I modified the code so that it ignores measurements that are not the same size as the data, so your test would return null. But after re-reading the question I realized there the OPs example data show a lot of instances of varying sizes, so I also added some best fitting variations.

Comment: Frankly your findClosestV2 and findClosestV3 are weak distance measurements for any real world problem I can think of. V2 rewards sets where ANY item is close to ANY item in the comparison set and it squares the scores, while linearly adding the results. V3 rewards alignments with high numerical values for no good reason (the % diff would be higher for low values with the same absolute diff). You need to analyze and define the problem and do the math before  any algorithm makes sense.